# How to get a full call stack in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, callstack, visual-c++-2005

How can I get a full call stack for a c++ application developed with Visual Studio 2005? I would like to have a full call stack including the code in the system libraries.

Do I have to change some settings in Visual Studio, or do I have to install additional software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get debug information for all project dependencies. This is specified under the "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General" section of the project properties.
2. On the menu, go to "Tools -> Options" then select "Debugging -> Symbols".
3. Add a new symbol location (the folder icon) that points to Microsoft's free symbol server “symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/downloads/symbols“
4. Fill out the "cache symbols" field with some place locally so you don't go to the internet all the time.

Comment: You might want to fix your misspelled "smysrv" in #3.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Clay, but for Symbols Server you should get the latest symsrv.DLL from "Debugging Tools For Windows", a free Microsoft download.

(Since you explicitly asked what you need to download, I presume you don't have it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Or, optionally (assuming that Visual Studio is not installed), grab a copy of [Windows Debugging Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx), install and either run your app from within the debugger (windbg.exe) or have it attach to an already running app:

> *windbg[.exe] -pn program.exe*
>
> or
> *windbg[.exe] -p process_id*

Break in the debugger at the point you want to observe for stack trace (Ctrl+Break). Switch to the thread of interest (most probably the main thread of execution):

> ~0s

Fix up symbols for system modules (and probably for the app as well if available):

> *  fix up symbols for app
> *.sympath path_to_app_symbols*
>
> *  configure where debugger will download and store system symbols
> *.symfix+ path_where_system_symbols_will_be_stored*
>
> * force debugger to reload symbols
> *.reload*

Issue a call stack command:

> *kb*