# C++ Visual Studio debugging with call stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, callstack

I have recently began learning C++ coming from a C# background. My problem is with the way exceptions get handled.

If I have a `nullptr` somewhere, resulting in reading from a forbidden location, then I get a nice looking callstack in VS like this:

[image: callstack]

However if I throw my own exception, or an assertion fails, then I do not get any clue as of what went wrong. VS just shows an error window:

[image]

**A:** This is kind of uncomfortable for me as in C# I would get a stacktrace in both case. Is there a way to print the stack trace? Or is there any plugin for VS to achieve this functionality?

**B:** And why is AccessViolationException different than our own thrown exceptions? Why don't we have a stacktrace for assertion failures?

**C:** How bad would it be, to create my own assert function, which would cause an AccessViolationException when assertion fails?

EDIT1: Yes, I should have read more carefully that messagebox instead of instantly clicking Abort. My bad.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio

Comment: Press 'Retry' on the assert message box and you should get a nice dialog that gives you options to debug the code, including seeing a callstack. For exceptions: you can do that too: you can turn on breaking on an exception being thrown, it's somewhere in the settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a full call stack in Visual Studio 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111023/how-to-get-a-full-call-stack-in-visual-studio-2005)

Comment: Yep, thanks Dave, this should be enough. But still Can someone answer me the question I raise in point B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And why is AccessViolationException different than our own thrown exceptions?

Because an AV is special, it is an exception that is triggered by the processor itself.  Raised when it signals that is no longer capable of executing code.  That's as bad a mishap as you can possibly imagine.  Recovering from an AV is very, very difficult and should in general never be attempted.  You cannot reason about the state of your program anymore, you don't know where it died beyond just a raw instruction address.

Catching and handling an AV is technically possible, you have to use Structured Exception Handling.  It requires using the non-standard __try and __except keywords in MSVC++.  But you should not do that, since handling an exception requires you to also restore the state of your program to the state it had before you ran the code that failed.  Impossible to do reliably since you cannot reason about that state anymore, you don't know what code was skipped by the exception.

You can get your program to shutdown in a somewhat reasonable way, it requires using the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() winapi function.  The equivalent of AppDomain.UnhandledException in C#.  All of this is entirely non-standard C++ of course.  The C++ standard dictates that a conforming C++ program should never invoke undefined behavior and does not specify what should happen when you do anyway.

This is otherwise a direct consequence of programming close to the metal.  There are a *lot* of counter-measures in managed code to prevent a program from ever getting into a state like this.  These counter-measure do not come for free, native C++ cares about making code run as fast as possible.  Losing diagnostics is part of that trade-off.  Don't invoke undefined behavior.